# Why Assignment Error not caught at Compile Time in Nim?

Tags: nim-lang

The code below produces `ObjectAssignmentError`, as far as I understand it's because the sequence defined as `seq[Doc]` and not as `seq[TextDoc]`.

But aren't such errors supposed to be caught at compile time, by compiler and not leak into runtime?

```
type
  Doc = object of RootObj

  TextDoc* = object of Doc
    title*: string
    text*:  string

  TodoDoc* = object of Doc
    todo*:     string

var all_docs*: seq[Doc] = @[]

all_docs.add TextDoc(title: "", text: "")
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason this isn't caught at compile time is because it's possible in general to add a `TextDoc` to an array of `Doc`, as long as they've been declared sensibly, i.e. heterogenous arrays have to be `ref objects` or Variants (otherwise they can't all fit in the same space)

to put it another way: inheritance means any procedure that accepts a `Doc` will also accept a `TextDoc`, including the procedure
`proc add(s:var seq[Doc],d:Doc)`

Nim supports value semantics, which are important for cache-friendliness, but that freedom can be unsettling to those used to e.g. Java where everything is passed by reference.

with reference semantics the above code runs with no errors:

```
type
  Doc = ref object of RootObj

  TextDoc* = ref object of Doc
    title*: string
    text*:  string

  TodoDoc* = ref object of Doc
    todo*:     string

var all_docs*: seq[Doc] = @[]

all_docs.add TextDoc(title: "", text: "blah")
assert TextDoc(all_docs[0]).text == "blah"
```